# Why does Ember 3.1 have trouble dealing with Ember Data proxied objects?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have an ES6 class in Ember 3.1 which is being handed an ember data object called `certifciate`. I would like to be able to call `.reload()` on that certificate as follows:

```
  @action
  showCertificateInfo(this: DomainCard, certificate) {
    this.setProperties({
      isShowingCertificateModal: true,
      selectedCert: certificate,
    })
    certificate
      .reload()
      .then(() => {
        this.set('isShowingCertificateModal', true)
      })
      .catch(e => {
        // TODO: handle this
      })
    }
```

However, if I do this, then Ember gives the following error/warning:

```
Assertion Failed: You attempted to access the 'reload' property 
(of <DS.PRomiseObject:ember796>)... However in this case4 the object 
in quetstion is a special kind of Ember object (a proxy). Therefore,
it is still necessary to use` .get(‘reload’)` in this case.
```

If I do as the code suggests and call `.get('reload')` instead, then I get an internal Ember error that `this` is not defined when calling `this._internalModel`. I get the same error when doing:

```
const reload = certificate.get('reload').bind(certificate)
reload().then()
...
```

What do I need to do to be able to reload this ember data object properly?

Comment: Your two answers are no answers. Please edit your original post if you want to provide additional information.

Comment: Have you tried `certificate.then(c => c.reload())`?

Comment: Yes, that did not work.

Comment: "Your two answers are no answers" @Lux -- I don't understand. The answers provided below both solve the error. Perhaps it would be helpful to display the model information in the original question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, whe fundamental problem seems to be that the certificate model had an async relationship to the domain model, and by using `{async: false}`, we remove the need to get a proxyPromise object returned to us and remove the need to pull the `content` object out of the promise.

Answer (score -1):

Pulling the content out of the proxy solved the problem:

```
const certContent = certificate.content || certificate
certContent.reload()
```

I'm still not sure why Ember 3.1 isn't able to work with the proxy properly, but this was the solution.